# Java 8 stream API - is there standard method for processing each value in Map to different type?

Tags: java, java-8

I learn [Java 8 Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html). In order to understand I try to make expression analog for SQL quesry:

```
select department, avg(salary) from employee group by department
```

for:

```
private static class Employee {
    public String name;
    public String department;
    public int salary;
}
```

Solution present in official tutorial:

```
empls.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> x.department,
        Collectors.averagingInt(x -> x.salary)))
```

Before I found this solution my strategy to calculate average with grouping:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> tmp =
    empls.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.department));
```

and applying functor to each value. But in `Map` interface there are no method to transform value into different type. In my case reduce List to `Double`. Standard SE API provide only method [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) that convert value to same type...

What Java 8 style method/trick/one-liner to convert `Map` value into different type? Worked like pseudo-code:

```
Map<K, V2> map2 = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<K, V1> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
     map2.add(entry.getKey(), Function<V1, V2>::apply(entry.getValue()));
 }
```

Comment: Which result do you want? A `Map<String, Double>` that maps each department name to an average salary? Or something else?

Comment: Transform `Map<K, V1>` to `Map<K, V2>` with standard SE library stream API + lambda.

Comment: Brian Goetz's answer does that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want:

```
Map<K, V2> map2 = 
    map1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                       e -> f.apply(e.getValue()));
```

where f is a function from V to V2.

Comment: Thanks! I think about `Entry` but don't know how to gather them back to `Map`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here working solution for exactly my example (here stream over stream loop for inner `List<Employee>`):

```
Map<String, Double> mapOfAverageSalaryByDepartment = 
    empls.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         Map.Entry::getKey,
         e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
               .average().getAsDouble()));
```