# Java 8 Streams for HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Below is the Map I use , but when I run I get sonar cycolmatic complexity. instead of this if else if else.. I would like to use Java 8 Stream. How to write this in Java 8 Streams... Please advice.

```
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
innerMap.put("ONE" , "ABC");
innerMap.put("TWO" , "DEF");
innerMap.put("THREE" , "GHI");

Map<String, Map<String,String> outerMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
outerMap.put("OUTER" , innerMap);

if(outerMap.containsKey("OUTER")){
    if(innerMap.containsKey("ONE")){
        call one method.....
    }else if (innerMap.containsKey("TWO")){
        call one  method....
    }else if (){
        .......
    }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: “but when I run I get sonar cycolmatic complexity” I have no idea, what you are trying to tell us.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can have behaviour parameterization. That means you can have a class(let's call it X) with 2 attributes - value(type=`String`), method(type=`Function`)

So, you can construct the Map like this:

```
Map<String, X> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("ONE" , new X("ABC", SomeClass::somemethod));
innerMap.put("TWO" , new X("DEF", SomeClass::somemethod2));
innerMap.put("THREE" , new X("GHI", SomeClass::somemethod3));
```

And then, you can just iterate the `entrySet()` of the map, and just call the `function.apply()`;

Comment: Thank you !!in my case the "innerMap" and "outerMap" are from a session which consumer app inserts. So what I understood is iterate the map and then add a class as said above ?

Comment: instead of iterating, if you have fixed handler methods for each type of key, define an interface of the handler, and create an enum which contains specific implementation handlers for each type of key. So you essentially do not have to write if else to determine which handler to call for each key type

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements priorities the key value that will be used to call a method, so unless that priority order is well-defined, there's probably no better way to do what you are doing.

It would be different if you were calling a method for each key present, but the `else` clause ensures that you're only calling the method for key `ONE`, even though there's also a key `TWO` and a key `THREE` in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to stream trough a nested `Map` using `flatMap`.

I would put the mappings between your input `String` and `Function` in a seperate Map.

```
public void withConsumerMap(){
    // Create a map of your functions too
    Map<String, Consumer<String>> functions = new HashMap<>();
    functions.put("ONE", this::one);

    Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    innerMap.put("ONE" , "ABC");
    innerMap.put("TWO" , "DEF");
    innerMap.put("THREE" , "GHI");

    Map<String, Map<String,String>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
    outerMap.put("OUTER" , innerMap);

    outerMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(outer -> outer.getKey().equals("OUTER"))
            .flatMap(outer -> outer.getValue().entrySet().stream())
            .forEach(inner -> functions.get(inner.getKey()).accept(inner.getValue()));
}

public void one(String param){ ... }
```

In the example above, I've used `java.util.function.Consumer`, which take one input, and returns `void`. If you need your functions to return something. Use `java.util.function.Function` instead.

Comment: Iterating over an entire map and filtering by comparing the key with a constant is perverting the `Map` concept. There is a reason why `Map` provides methods like `get` or `containsKey`. It’s because these operations can be implemented efficiently using the way the actual map implementation works. Depending on the implementation, they have time complexity of `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` and you are ignoring them and use an `O(n)` operation instead.

Comment: @Holger I think you are missing the point. My example code shows an example of how you can use streams to iterate over `Maps`. It doesn't show the optimal code to solve this type of problem. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: The primary goal of SO is to *solve problems* not to show how to do something with arbitrary premises, ignoring the strong reasons to never do it that way. The minimum to do would be to mention the reasons, not to do it, right in the answer. But the better answer would be “don’t to it with streams, they don’t solve your problem”.

Comment: There are completely valid reasons for iterating trough maps, and doing operations on them. Sometimes you get a `Map` returned from a 3rd party library, and you want to do operations on every entry in the map.

When in a year, someone is looking for a way to use streams with Maps, finds this post. They can look at my solution, and apply it to their problem.

That's more usefull, then just saying "never ever do it".

Comment: Don’t be ridiculous. There are tons of examples on StackOverflow showing how to iterate over a `Map` *when it is useful*. Nobody needs “your solution” placed in a context where it is *not* useful. And if anybody searches for something like how to process a map using streams, old question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24986266) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21233183), just to name two, are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it this way? Why do you need streams for this?

```
 Map<String, Runnable> executionPath = new HashMap<>();
    executionPath.put("OUTER-ONE", runnable1);
    executionPath.put("OUTER-TWO", runnable2);

    // I guess you want to pass the arg - such as "OUTER-ONE"

    executor.execute(executionPath.get(arg));
```